# Не работает apt/apt-get/sudo в Ubuntu на Putty

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

Решил попробовать опубликовать небольшой сайт на python на хостинге и для ssh соединения решил воспользоваться Putty. Все бы ничего, но при установки python работая в Putty получил ошибку и предупреждение об отсутствии и необходимости пакета gcc. Попытался установить стандартным пакетным установщиком apt/apt-get. Потом с sudo пытался (При входе в систему я использую логин и пароль, которые я указывал при создании FTP-аккаунта (beget). Так что я думаю это не пользователь имеющий root доступ). Даже подумал о том, что случайно ошибся с операционкой и попробовал yum. На любую команду я получаю:`-bash: apt/apt-get/sudo/yum: command not found`. Немного не понимаю, что делать.. Ubuntu уже была установлена при первом запуске putty поэтому проблем не должно быть никаких. Честно сказать полный новичок в этом, очень прошу помощи!

Answer (score 2):

cat /etc/*-release покажет версию дистра

w укажет юзера

users покажет список юзеров

на вводе root через решетку, а юзер через $, ctrl+D выйти из root

можно попробовать

```
dpkg -s gcc 
apt-cache gcc
```

ну либо поискать ман по командам пакетника, какой то пакетник должен все равно быть если ничего не удалялось руками, то есть надо узнать имя дистра, посмотреть какой менеджер пакетов там используется, погуглить мануал по командам и пользоваться через sudo или sudo -s

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Проверил все возможное, работает только dpkg здесь, но ему не хватает прав что-либо установить или просмотреть. sudo -i опять же не работает... Пишет, что sudo команда не найдена. Пробовал dpkg с разными флагами запускать-нет. apt-cache кстати тоже отказался работать. Его нету здесь. Чудеса какие-то..